# which monitoring tool is good for monitoring system hardware,software,user management and network activity for all kind of operating system?

Tags: linux, windows, monitoring, network-monitoring, system-monitoring

Please kindly suggest me the tool for monitoring the system hardware, software, applications, services, user management and network related activities of IT Infrastructure.

Comment: **Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations** are considered [**off-topic**](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on serverfault.com. Potentially your question can be reworded or made suitable for the  [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Stack Exchange community, but before posting, please read their guidelines. Alternatively Wikipedia often has [lists of available products.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems)

Answer (score 1):

Nagios. You can build custom monitoring scripts to monitor just about anything but there are plugins available for common items such as network connectivity, space, cpu and memory utilization, bandwidth etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have used Nagios but I want a tool for monitoring my IT Infrastructure inventories+Network activities+user activity+ software monitoring.